# how to select multiple values from a linq query and display as list

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, linq

I would like to know how I can retrieve  values that matches specific criteria using a linq query in asp.net mvc c#. As shown in my code below I have used a 
the .First() method  however this seems to retrieve the first value it finds , I however want to retrieve the values that matche the criteria in specified in the query . Please bear in mind that I have declared that variable that holds that value as a string however that makes it impossible to retrieve a list of values . I tried to change the select line to `select new { cas.Description, das.AssetInstanceID }).AsEnumerable;` but I get an error saying "cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed local variable"

```
 costCentreEntities = context.tbl_Organisation_CostCentre.Where(c => c.CostCentreID == userCostCentre && c.IsDeleted != true).OrderBy(c => c.CostCentreDesc);
                var deviceDescription = (from cas in context.tbl_Organisation_CostCentreAssetSIM
                join oc in context.tbl_Organisation_CostCentre
                on cas.CostCentreID equals oc.CostCentreID
                join das in context.tbl_Device_AssetSensor
                on cas.AssetInstanceID equals das.AssetInstanceID
                where das.ParentAssetInstanceID == null
                select new { cas.Description, das.AssetInstanceID }).FirstOrDefault();
                assetDescription = deviceDescription.Description;
                assetId = deviceDescription.AssetInstanceID;
               return costCentreEntities.ToList().Select(cc => new DeviceMetricItem(cc.CostCentreID, assetId, null, null, cc.ContractID, assetDescription, cc.CostCentreDesc, cc.tbl_Organisation_CostCentre1.Count)).ToList();
```

below is my dtos/class where I have declared the variables that are holding the desired values , please pay attention to the description and assetInstanceId variables that in actual fact should be capable of holding one or more values as opposed to only one

```
public DeviceMetricItem(int ? CostCentreID , int? AssetInstanceId,  int? ParentCostCentreId, int? classificationId,   int ? ContractID , string Description , string CostCentreDesc ,  int NoChildren = 0 )
        {
            costCentreId = CostCentreID.HasValue ?  CostCentreID.Value:0;
            assetInstanceId = AssetInstanceId.HasValue ? AssetInstanceId.Value : 0;
            parentCostCentreId = ParentCostCentreId.HasValue ? ParentCostCentreId.Value : 0; 
            classificationId = classificationId.HasValue? classificationId.Value:0; 
            ContractID = ContractID.HasValue ? ContractID.Value:0;
            description = Description;
            costCentreDesc = CostCentreDesc ?? string.Empty;
            noChildren = NoChildren ;
    }
    public int costCentreId { get; set; }
    public string costCentreDesc { get; set; }
    public int assetInstanceId { get; set; }
    public int parentCostCentreId { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public int noChildren { get; set;}
    public int contractId { get; set; }
```

Comment: @GertArnold I removed FirstOrDefault  and it says there is anonymous type does not include a definition for description. I also tried adding  AsEnumerable but I get an error saying "cannot assign method group to an implicitly typed local variable"

Comment: You know, this horizontal scrolling instantly turns me into a dyslectic. Anyway, you can't do `ToList` on the result of `FirstOrDefault()`. It should be an `IEnumerable`. Or else you should just construct one `DeviceMetricItem` (i.e.not by a `Select`), copying the properties of `deviceDescription` to it.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks mate that worked